# Justification of an assumption in fluid mechanics (free surface)

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What justifies this assumption on the free surface of the sea, taken from Faltinson's book (page 15), for a potential flow?

> A fluid particle on the free-surface is assumed to stay on the free-surface

Comment: At the free surface, there is no shear. Therefore we cannot have any viscous effects that would deviate the particle from it's path.